# Play framework offline distribution downloads repositories

Tags: java, maven, playframework, sbt, ivy

I downloaded the offline distribution - version 2.3.2 - of Play Framework, where I see it includes a repository with a bunch of libraries. When, though, I create a new project, it starts downloading all these libraries again.

What's the point in doing that?

Is there a way I can define the repository I already have - the one I downloaded with the offline distro?

Or, at least, can I define a different directory when it starts downloading all these libraries? I don't want them in C: drive.

Answer (score 1):

Play 2.3 uses default ivy cache directory ([What’s new in Play 2.3](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Highlights23)) which points to `${user.home}/.ivy2`. Path is defined inside `activator-launch-X.X.X.jar` in file `sbt/sbt.boot.properties`.

To change the path you need to extract file from jar using:

```
jar -xvf activator-launch-X.X.X.jar sbt.boot.properties
```

Edit extracted file `sbt.boot.properties` and replace `${user.home}/.ivy2`:

```
[ivy]
  ivy-home: ${user.home}/.ivy2
```

Replace old file in jar with new one using:

```
jar -uvf activator-launch-X.X.X.jar sbt.boot.properties
```